# How Can i get numbered list of items or texts in flutter within a container or a card?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hi I'm trying to find my way in flutter, but couldn't get a numbered list in a card or a container, like this :

1. First text
2. Second text
3. Third text

but also a list from right to left, And if possible making the numbers in a circle design.

Comment: Are you using ListView builder for rendering list?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ListView.builder` then it's pretty easy.

Here is the example:

```
List<String> list =["first text", "second text", "third text"];

...
// Now you can render this list with numbering with ListView.builder easily.

ListView.builder
  (
    itemCount: list.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
     return new Text(index.toString()+ "."+list[index]);
    }
  )

/*
PS: answering this from mobile so couldn't give you the  whole example.
But I hope you got the general idea.
*/
```

To make it render number in circle then instead of returning simple Text widget like we did in above example we need to return Row widget having two children, CircleAvatar and Text.

Example :

```
ListView.builder
  (
    itemCount: list.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
     return Row( children: [
          CircleAvatar(
              child: Text(index.toString())
               ),
          Text(list[index]),
       );
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using the .asMap() method, here is how I have done it:

```
...meal.steps.asMap().entries.map((step) => Text("${step.key + 1}. ${step.value}"),
      )),
```

you can use .key to access the index of the list item and increment it by 1 to display the numbered list.